# Android case context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType, pck):

Tags: android, expression, constants

In My Android app: **I replaced R.id.** with **MyR.getResId()**.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case MyR.getResId(getApplicationContext(), "id", "title_left_image "):                       
            exit();
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }

}
```

But returns an exception message：

> case expressions must be constant expressions

here is my MyR code：

```
public class MyR {
public static int getResId(Context context, String resType, String resName) {
    int resId = 0;       
    String pck = context.getPackageName();   
    if (resId <= 0) {
        resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType, pck);
        if (resId <= 0)
            resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                    resName.toLowerCase(), resType, pck);
    }
final int rid = resId;
    return rid ;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == MyR.getResId(getApplicationContext(), "id", "title_left_image ")){
           exit();
    } 
}
```